# jQuery Slide-out effect issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm trying to use the function below to get a DIV to slide-out from left to right when clicked on but it doesn't even move. Any ideas what the problems could be.

Function

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$("#teller").click(function () {
      $(this).show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 1000);
});
</script>
```

DIV in question

```
<div id="teller">
<a href="#"><img src="images/teller.png" width="44" height="329" alt="Tell a freind button" />
</a>
</div><!-- End Teller -->
```

Comment: You should setup a jsfiddle. edit this one if you need to: http://jsfiddle.net/4x8VC/

Comment: Are you using jquery UI I assume?

Comment: ... I'm confused. if `#teller` is supposed to slide out, how can it also be the one to fire the event? You're example code doesn't have `#teller` hidden, but shouldn't it be if you're going to `show` it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
 $(this).show("slideOut", { direction: "right" }, 1000);
```

Use `slide`

```
 $(this).show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 1000);
```

If its already visible and you want to slide out, use a combination of hide and slide right

```
$(this).hide("slide", { direction: "right" }, 1000);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use scale to grow it right:

```
  $(this).effect("scale", { percent: 400, direction: 'horizontal' }, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think for this instance you just probably have a typo:  'slideOut' is not actually an effect type for jQuery UI  it's just "slide" and then you give it the direction like you did.  To slide it in you can `.show()` it like you are, and to slide it out you can use `.hide()`